# Best approach to bind reference property of object to dropdownlist in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, properties, bind

I got an entity like this:

```
public class Asset
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Location { get; set; }
}
```

I try to bind the "location" property, using dropdownlistfor:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Location.Id, new SelectList(ViewBag.Departments, "Id", "Name", Model.Location), "--- empty ---")
```

But I need ability to leave location field empty. And the question is how to accomplish this best way?

Comment: When you say "empty", do you mean that Location is null?  Or that it contains some default value?  or is Id null?

Comment: I wanna set location to NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DropDownListFor Required following syntax and i found issue when you pass Location as your selected index property.

Instead of this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Location.Id, new SelectList(ViewBag.Departments, "Id", "Name", **Model.Location**), "--- empty ---")
```

Try This

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Location.Id, new SelectList(ViewBag.Departments, "Id", "Name", Model.Location == null ? 0 : Model.Location.Id), "--- empty ---")
```

Comment: I try to use this code snippet, so when i submit page i got a following error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items". Next I change it to @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Location, new SelectList(ViewBag.Departments, "Id", "Name", Model.Location), "--- empty ---") and it works perfect only if I not provide the location property (left it empty). Otherwise, i got the same "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items" exception. I can't understand, what's happen behind the scene and which items are NULL?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Asset
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Location { get; set; }
    public Asset(){
       this.Location=  new Department();
    }
}
```

Comment: Same result:"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items". Last line of stack trace before exception is "System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items, String dataValueField, String dataTextField, IEnumerable selectedValues)", so I think that problem actually is about wrong binding.